# Begin at head of a list after iterating through it

Tags: list, loops, haskell

I have a function that checks if there is an element from one list in a tuple of another list.

```
existing :: [String] -> [(String,Int)] -> [String]
existing [] _ = []
existing _ [] = []
existing (x:xs) (y:ys) = if x == fst(y) then x:(existing xs (y:ys)) else (existing (x:xs) ys)
                                                            ^^^^^^
                                                   It should start at the beginning.
```

As you can see it iterates through the y-list and checks if x is in there. When found it should check the y-list if the next item from the x list but it cant because it is at the position where the x is found. I hope you get what i mean.

Comment: The function you are trying to write is essentially `intersect` or `intersectBy` from `Data.List`. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember what the beginning of the list was and you'll be able to go back to it.

```
existing :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a, b)] -> [a]
existing allxs allys = go allxs allys
    where
        go [] _ = []
        go _ [] = []
        go (x:xs) (y:ys) =
            if x == fst(y)
            then x:(go xs allys)
            else (go (x:xs) ys)
```

Comment: `go (x:xs) [] = go xs allys`?